# How to round a hour to the nearest 2 hour interval with PHP?

Tags: php

I have 4 time values:

```
$times = array('16:04:12', '16:57:54', '17:59:59', '18:00:00');
```

I would like to divide the 24 hour time to 2 hour intervals so I will have 12 hours, like: `0:00:01-1:59:59, 2:00:00-3:59:59, 4:00:00-5:59:59, etc.`

What I want to do is place these values into those intervals. So the final result should be:

```
$result = array(
    '16:00:00-17:59:59' => array('16:04:12', '16:57:54', '17:59:59'),
    '18:00:00-19:59:59' => array('18:00:00')
);
```

I have tried to create an array with the intervals and then loop through it checking if one is bigger than the other, but it did not work as intended.

How is it possible to put the hours into these 2 hour intervals?

Comment: Convert your time into a number with strtotime to create intervals and then compare your input values with the bounds of those intervals0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you should just compare hours

and don't write some sophisticated and unreadable code.

For example:

```
<?php

$times = array('16:04:12', '16:57:54', '17:59:59', '18:00:00');
foreach ($times as $t) {
    // extract hour from string
    $h = substr($t, 0, 2);
    if ($h%2 === 0) {
        $key = sprintf('%02d:00:00-%02d:59:59', $h, $h+2);
    } else {
        $key = sprintf('%02d:00:00-%02d:59:59', $h-1, $h+1);
    }
    // this key will resolve all values
    $r[$key][] = $t;
}
var_export($r);
```

This will prints:

```
array (
  '16:00:00-18:59:59' => 
  array (
    0 => '16:04:12',
    1 => '16:57:54',
    2 => '17:59:59',
  ),
  '18:00:00-20:59:59' => 
  array (
    0 => '18:00:00',
  ),
)
```

Hope it will help you, because this code looks very understandable...

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two hour groups and initialize as empty array in `$result`

```
$result = array(
    '16:00:00-17:59:59' => array(),
    '18:00:00-19:59:59' => array()
);

for($i=0;$i<count($times);$i++)
{
        $date = strtotime($times[$i]);
        $hour= date('H', $date);

        if($hour%2==0)
            $hour=$hour;
        else 
            $hour=$hour-1;  

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if(substr($key,0,2)===$hour)
            {
                if(count($result[$key])==0)
                    $result[$key][0]=$times[$i];
                else
                    $result[$key][count($result[$key])+1]=$times[$i];               
            }
        }
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

**OUPUT**

> Array ( [16:00:00-17:59:59] => Array ( [0] => 16:04:12 [2] => 16:57:54
>   ) [18:00:00-19:59:59] => Array ( [0] => 18:00:00 ) )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an array with all the time_intervals even if no time exists for that period then you can use the following code. So if you want to skip those periods that have not times in their zone you can do a foreach and skip those keys that have empty values.

```
$times = array('16:04:12', '16:57:54', '17:59:59', '18:00:00');
$interval = 2;
$time_intervals = array();
//Populate time intervals
for($i = 0; $i < 23; $i += $interval) {
    $from = str_pad($i,  2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':00:00';
    $to = str_pad($i + 1,  2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).':59:59';
    $time_intervals[$from.'-'.$to] = array();
}
//Check through all time values
foreach($times as $time) {
    foreach($time_intervals as $key => $value) {
        $zone = explode('-', $key);
        $from = $zone[0];
        $to = $zone[1];
        if (strtotime($time) >= strtotime($from) && strtotime($time) <= strtotime($to)) {
            $time_intervals[$key][] = $time;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($time_intervals);
```

Result:

```
array (size=12)
  '00:00:00-01:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '02:00:00-03:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '04:00:00-05:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '06:00:00-07:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '08:00:00-09:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '10:00:00-11:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '12:00:00-13:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '14:00:00-15:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '16:00:00-17:59:59' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '16:04:12' (length=8)
      1 => string '16:57:54' (length=8)
      2 => string '17:59:59' (length=8)
  '18:00:00-19:59:59' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '18:00:00' (length=8)
  '20:00:00-21:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '22:00:00-23:59:59' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a 2 hour interval, just add modulo 2 to the time

example

```
for($x=1;$x<=23;$x++)
{
 echo $x.': '.($x+$x%2).'<br />';
}
```